# Excel Sumifs with Multiple OR Criteria

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to build a Sumifs formula that uses multiple OR criteria, but also uses cell references in the criteria.  I've found on other posts how to use an array constant (ie. Sumifs('Sum Range', 'Criteria Range', {value 1, value 2})) to achieve this, but array constants don't allow for cell references; only static-defined values.

Here's a simplified example my data: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdfCN.png

I need to build a Sumifs formula in cell 'TABLE B'!C2 which returns the sum of Price values from column 'TABLE A'!C:C where:

```
('Table A'!A:A = 'TABLE B'!A:A or "ALL") AND ('Table A'!B:B = 'TABLE B'!B:B or "ALL")
```

This formula should return a value in 'TABLE B'!C2 of:

```
'TABLE A'!C3 +'TABLE A'!C4 + 'TABLE A'!C5  
= $9.00
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You would use this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((('Table A'!$A$2:$A$5='TABLE B'!A2)+('Table A'!$A$2:$A$5="ALL"))*(('Table A'!$B$2:$B$5='TABLE B'!B2)+('Table A'!$B$2:$B$5="All")),'Table A'!$C$2:$C$5)
```

Comment: Appreciate it Scott!